# How to order items using jQuery or css on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two main buttons which each contain child buttons detail, on desktop everything works fine. I want for each parent sub buttons to be displayed below its parent, here what I have so far:

HTML

```
<div class="main-data">
   <div class="main-data_butttons">
      <div class="main-data_button-left">Trump</div>
      <div class="main-data_button-right">Babab Yaga</div>
   </div>
   <div class="main-data-buttons-left_details">
      <div class="main-data-buttons_details-first">Test</div>
      <div class="main-data-buttons_details-second">Test</div>
      <div class="main-data-buttons_details-third">Test</div>
      <div class="main-data-buttons_details-fourth">Test</div>
   </div>
   <div class="main-data-buttons-right_details">
      <div class="main-data-buttons_details-first">Test</div>
      <div class="main-data-buttons_details-second">Test</div>
      <div class="main-data-buttons_details-third">Test</div>
      <div class="main-data-buttons_details-fourth">Test</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

On the desktop looks something like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this on mobile:

[image]

On mobile two buttons are displayed when you click one of them it display hidden data all of this I managed to do but I can't figure out to make those sub buttons to display under each main button, right now everything is displayed below two main buttons, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally i'd rearrange that DOM a little so those main buttons were in blocks with its content. This way u can control the behavior with CSS better. You define the looks from the lowest resolution and progress your way up.

- on low resolution you're basically done
- on higher resolutions (defined by @media (min-width: 600px)) you float the main blocks next to each other
- you can even add more blocks on higher resolutions, if you want, with another media query, for example @media (min-width: 1200px) and make .main-data { width: 33.333333% } and so on

The point is, it's not easy to rearrange DOM in CSS. At least not in your case. You can use javascript of course, but you would need some changes in DOM anyway.

```js
var $mainDataButton = $('.main-data-button');

$mainDataButton.on('click', function() {
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; } 

.main-data-button, 
.main-data-buttons div { display: inline-block; margin: 5px; border: 1px solid purple; padding: 10px; background: #fafafa; }
.main-data-button { padding: 30px; }
.main-data-buttons { display: none; }

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .main-data { float: left; width: 50%; }
  .main-data-buttons { display: block !important; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-data">
 <div class="main-data-button">Main button left</div>
 <div class="main-data-buttons">
  <div class="main-data-buttons_details-first">Test</div>
  <div class="main-data-buttons_details-second">Test</div>
  <div class="main-data-buttons_details-third">Test</div>
  <div class="main-data-buttons_details-fourth">Test</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="main-data">
 <div class="main-data-button">Main button right</div>
 <div class="main-data-buttons">
  <div class="main-data-buttons_details-first">Test</div>
  <div class="main-data-buttons_details-second">Test</div>
  <div class="main-data-buttons_details-third">Test</div>
  <div class="main-data-buttons_details-fourth">Test</div>
 </div>
</div>
```